# Where does [reflection.assembly] reside?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In a disconnected DEV box, I attempt to load the reflection assembly, "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO". Then I try to call for a SMO.Server object, like this

```
[Reflection.assembly]::("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
```

Powershell responds with this error message

> New-Object : Cannot find type {Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO.Server]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

So I get it. I need to find a copy of the assembly, download it to a USB device, and upload it to my disconnected DEV server.  Where do I find the assembly to download?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.timextender.com/hc/en-us/articles/210437663-Error-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-Microsoft-SqlServer-ConnectionInfo-

## Cause

You have not installed the SQL Shared Management Objects (SMO). They are needed to create tables and other SQL objects from TX.

## Resolution

Download the SQL Shared Management Objects from the SQL Server Feature Packages and install it. The download sites are linked below - the file you need is called SharedManagementObjects.msi.

[SQL Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)

[SQL Server 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

[SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)

[SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30440)

[SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375)

[SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11988)

[SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo)

Many thanks to Tobias Eld and my apologies to the net for not finding this resource before I posted this question.